# Spark - Performing read of large file results in multiplication of dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm currently running a script that performs a very simple read on a rather large pipe delimited file (~870,000 records with 28 columns). Code below for reference:

```
readFile = spark.read.option("delimiter", inputFileDemiliter).csv(inputPath, mode = readMode, \
                    header=True, inferSchema=False,schema = schema)
```

The issue is, if I perform a simple count on the dataframe, readFile, I'm getting a record count of about 14 million (it's 16.59 times the initial record count, to be exact).

I imagine it has something to do with replication. We could perform a dedup on the primary key column, but we shouldn't be getting this issue in the first place and so want to avoid that.

Does anyone know how to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: I found that if I read the file from a local directory, the record count remains accurate. The issue happens if I try to read it from an HDFS path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was due to an encryption service which was active on our HDFS directory. Encryption would mess with the number of delimiters in our file, hence the whacky record count.